# setTextSize method doesn't work by using LayoutInflater :

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I want to implement *changeTextSize1* method(in SettingActivity.java) when I click a *textView*(not included in below codes).
*changeTextSize1* is method that changes *textsize* of finalT textView.
But it doesn't work.

**SettingActivity.java**

```
 public void changeTextSize1(View v) {

    TextView ts1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textsize1);
    TextView ts2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textsize2);
    TextView ts3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textsize3);
    ts1.setTypeface(ts1.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
    ts2.setTypeface(ts2.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);
    ts3.setTypeface(ts3.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);

    View view = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.recycler_todo, null);

    TextView finalT = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.finalText);
    finalT.setTextSize(22);
}
```

recycler_todo.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#56A2B7"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/finalText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="text"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

belows are more codes.

MyAdapter.java

```
public MyAdapter(ArrayList<TodoList> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_todo, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="672dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#56A2B7">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bVc5.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St9dF.jpg)

First Image : If i click that "1" TextView... →
Second Image : That sentence needs to be more bigger...

More codes are needed?

Comment: Where did you use `recycler_todo.xml` exactly?

Comment: It is main recyclerview of my project. linked with MainActivity.

Comment: If `recycler_todo` is an item of your `RecyclerView`, that's not how you supposed to access its inside views.

Comment: I am a beginner of Android Studio. So, I'm not sure that the xml document is an item of my RecyclerView. (But I put items by using ArrayList in MainActivity) Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I'd like to help if I understand the exact case you're facing. Post more code so that I can get what you're trying to do and find the culprit.

Comment: try this:
`View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_add_category_dialog, null);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohhk, So first of all you want to change your item's text size from your Settings screen, which you want to be reflected in your adaptor.

and then, you just need to save that text size into [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences), and then, in **MyAdapter** ***onBindViewHolder*** method, read the text size from settings, and set to your textview, its that easy.

Here is the small problem,

```
public MyAdapter(ArrayList<TodoList> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    // HERE YOUR CODE GOES TO SET TEXT SIZE FROM SETTING
    holder.textview.setText(readSizeFromSharedPreference())
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work.. I think java source code is not main problem. Another reason that I couldn't find is surely exist. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: ohh my friend, you just inflated a layout, and changed its text size, you didn't displayed any code that you are using to inject that view in any container. obviously, it is not still added to UI.

Comment: oh.. i understand it...little... umm... you mean that.. I need to make container that can take a view what i made by using inflater? could you give me some example code? it's so hard....